# C# List values compare and add

Tags: c#, list

```
var bndlSummary = GetBundleSummary(GroupIds);
var cntrSummary = GetContainerSummary(GroupIds);
var finalSummary = GetFinalSummary(GroupIds);
```

Above var are fetching some data from Database. They all have one Common Field Name "City". 
City value can be repeated many time like  City = Chicago can be 3 times or more). now I want this Field City value into allCityNames. I don't want City Info to be repeated from any var.

```
var allCityNames = new cityAnalysisSummary();
```

Please help me how how should i do it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: First of all, what types are the bndlSummary, cntrlSummary, finalSummary? are they all of type List<Summary> or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
bndlSummary.Select(b => b.City)
           .Concat(cntrSummary.Select(c => c.City))
           .Concat(finalSummary.Select(f => f.City))
           .Distinct();
```

Use `Select` to get all the cities from each collection, `Concat` to put them all together, and `Distinct` to remove any duplicates.

You can also use `Union` which will remove duplicates while concatenating:

```
bndlSummary.Select(b => b.City)
           .Union(cntrSummary.Select(c => c.City))
           .Union(finalSummary.Select(f => f.City));
```

Comment: You can use [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) which is basically the same as `Concat` except it removes duplicates, thus not needing to use `Distinct`.

Comment: @vcsjones as long as none are repeated within a collection that would work. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET your first .Concat should be .Concat(cntrSummary.Select(c => c.City)) not .Concat(cntr.Select(c => c.City))

Comment: @Selman22: Not if it is a primitive type like `string` or `int`

Comment: @vcsjones yea I didn't get your point first. you meant `bndlSummary.Select(b => b.City).Union(cntr.Select(c => c.City))` ...